# Gather data points in an irregular shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cluster-analysis, visualization

I am working on the visualization of a cluster analysis problem.

I have 5 centers defined by 5 points in a 2d space. This centers will define classes this way:

> The class of every data-point is defined by the closest center to it (euclidean distance).

I did the work to define the class of every data-point but I am looking for a way to gather all the data of the same cluster in an irregular shape.

What I tried so far is this:

[image]

The problem is that when I use the `circle` form, some of data-points that belong to one class will be outside.

Is there some way to gather each cluster in an irregular shape with smooth border?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a Voronoi diagram. D3 has [some functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Voronoi-Geom) for working with them.